# How to list messages in order in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, messaging, django-channels

SO I have been trying to implement a basic one to one chat system in Django. So far, I have created a model that takes in two foreign keys( sender, recipient) and a Charfield by the name of message.

```
class message(models.Model):
    sender=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='sender2',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='reciever2',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message1=models.CharField(max_length=10000000)
```

Now, I am able to create message objects but what I want to do is display in a back-and forth conversation on one single page. I have so far been able to fetch all messages for a particular "sender-receiver" combination.

```
def view_message(request,pk):
    client1=User.objects.get(id=pk)
    client2=request.user
    message1=message.objects.filter(sender=client1,receiver=client2).all()
    return render(request,'message.html',{'messages':message1})
```

Now the above view just shows all messages for the single user who logged in, sent to the other user whose Primary key is being used/clicked on,
But I also want to show are "replies" they receive in a conversation-style manner and in order.
Hopefully, You guys understand what I am saying here.
A one-to-one private messaging system (not asynchronous), so the page can refresh and reload all messages sent and received but in order.
Thank you :)

Comment: did you try `message.objects.filter(sender=client1, receiver=client2).order_by('-pk')` ?

Comment: Just tried it, It just lists one side of the conversation. Like for where the sender is client1, I want to be able to show messages where the sender becomes the recipient

Comment: ok, then you need to filter out those records ;) i mean, currently your query covers only messages sent from `client1`, to include messages sent from `client2`, do: `message.objects.filter(Q(sender=client1,receiver=client2) | Q(sender=client1,receiver=client2)).order_by('-pk')`, don't forget to import `Q` object: `from django.db.models import Q`

Comment: oops, i made a semantic error in the previous comment, try this instead: `message.objects.filter(Q(sender=client1, receiver=client2) | Q(sender=client2, receiver=client1)).order_by('-pk')`

Comment: workes great :D. Thanks alot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a date created field `created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` to your model, due to how databases work PK is not going to be perfectly ordered (each connection might be given a chunk of PKs to use, this results in non perfect ordering, best is to use a timestamp)